# "zpool create" with encryption enabled raises error "URI scheme is not supported"

Tags: 18.04, zfs

I got this command to work on an existing system, but on fresh installs of Ubuntu 18.04.5, with `zfs-dkms` installed from `ppa:jonathonf/zfs` I get:

```
ubuntu@hdp1-sitka:~$ sudo zpool create -f -O encryption=aes-256-gcm -O keyformat=raw -O keylocation=file:///etc/zfs.key tank sda sdb sdd sde sdf sdg sdh sdi sdj sdk sdl
cannot create 'tank': URI scheme is not supported
```

Yes, I'm striping 11 disks together. They'll serve a hadoop datanode. ZFS makes it convenient to balance different sized disks together and do inline encryption.

The error is specific to `-O keylocation=file:///etc/zfs.key` and feels like a missing dependency to grok `file:///` URIs.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the system enables this command to run. The PPA author confirmed that a system reboot is required to enable the kernel module.

Comment: This does not weigh up to an answer, is better suited as a comment.

Comment: It looks like an answer to me.

Comment: This answer fixed the problem for me. I would prefer an answer that doesn't involve rebooting. The PPA author wrote me and confirmed that a reboot is required to get the kernel module loaded, so apparently, this is THE answer.